# how can I get all reverse relation names in the Django model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

how can I get all reverse relation names in the Django model?

I wanna know all related_name that link to my model, How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using `Model._meta.related_objects` which contains a list of all related models.

Example:

```
for rel in Model._meta.related_objects:
    print(rel.related_name)
```

I think this will show all Many to One and Many to Many relations pointing to your model.